# C ncurses tabsize

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to figure how to change TABSIZE in ncurses, and found the set_tabsize function. I tried it and it simply produces a wrong effect. Simple program to test it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    initscr(); set_tabsize(4); noecho();
    printw("a\tb\na    b");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expect my tabs to be 4 spaces but the output is:

```
a   b
a    b
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: the column numbers start (in C) at 0, so the first tab stop, when tabsize is 4 would be in column 3, the next tab stop would be in column 7, etc.  Note: with the default tab size of 8, the first tab stop is in column 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs aren't typically four spaces, they typically go to tab-stops which are each four spaces wide. For that reason, the following code will all produce the same spacing:

```
printf("a\tb\n");      a   b
printf("aa\tb\n");     aa  b
printf("aaa\tb\n");    aaa b
```

Answer (score 2):

You're confused about tabs - they don't expand to a fixed number of spaces - they insert enough spaces to take you to the next tab column. So in the first line you get 3 spaces for your tab.